# Responsive Nav Bar will not sit centrally in DIV

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I've done lots of searching and testing on possible solutions, but can't get this responsive menu to sit central.

```
  /**********HEADER ***************************/

.headerbar {
  display:inline-block;
   width:100%;
    background:#007700;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
/******************/


/*********** NAVBACKER *********************/
.navback {
    display:block;
    height:32px;
    border:2px solid grey;
    background:grey;
    margin:auto;
}
/***************/



/* START OF NAV STYLES ****************************/
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;

}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;

}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #003300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:1px solid green;

}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: #006600;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #006600;
    color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #003300;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;

}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
        height:12px;
    }
}
/* END OF NAV STYLES ****************

    <div class="headerbar">
    <h1>Logo and some text</h1>
</div>

<div class="navback">
<!-- START OF NAVIGATION MENU -->
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
        <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Latest ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Comments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Threads</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Explore ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">Counties</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Towns</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Attractions</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Picture Tours</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
<!-- END OF NAVIGATION MENU -->`enter code here`
```

Here is where I have been trying to get it to work: [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/treetops/p5oypc72/69/)

Every time I change the **position:absolute**, the menu when hovered, formats wrong. I've also tried **margin:0 auto;** etc but nothing I've tried will work, and I've tried removing the **float**. Any help is hugely appreciated.
Tree

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here, sorry it's early and I'm a little confused. Could you post some form of diagram or further explanation please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
```

in ul tag, like this:

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/p5oypc72/70/

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I'm new to CSS. As my site already has hundreds of styles, including ones for <UL> and so on, I'm now trying to give everything in the new Navigation bar a unique ID. I thought I could do this by wrapping a <div id="navigation"> around it, and then applying the ID to all the elements of the list, but after doing so the hover links cease to work. Please see here [link]http://jsfiddle.net/treetops/v8m47thu/